# Change Browser Size to Specific height/width?

Tags: jquery, resize, window

Since there doesn't seem to be a way for a user to take a screenshot of a webpage without using some sort of plugin, i figured i'd at least cater to the plug-ins. For example, Pagesaver, for firefox, lets me save just the visible portion of the website i'm viewing. To cater to this, i'd like to develop a script that changes my window size to the boundaries of a relevant parent div, or to a static width/height.

For example, i have a site with a static width and WS on the sides. I'd like to have a button that when clicked, changes the window's width to the width of the center column, so that no WS shows. (same goes for height if the page isn't full height) This way, if they have a plug-in like pagesaver, they aren't saving useless portions of the site.

Is this possible? It doesn't necessarily have to be a new window, resizing the current window would probably be less work/preferred. I know ads do this to me all the time, so it must be possible...

Comment: Please don’t do that. I hate it when a web page means to believe that it needs to resize *my* browser window.

Comment: Please don't. My window size is none of your business; _changing it_ is going over the line.

Comment: plugins like Pagesaver should add this feature. It is not your responsibility to resize your window for them. I am pretty sure that I won't prefer this if I was your user/client/lead/manager/CEO/anyone.

Comment: I understand that it's annoying yes, but this is a case where it really does help the user. (hopefully) And yeah, i agree that pagesaver and ilk should implement some sort of selection (either marquee like or element based) for saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the window is easy, but I think resizing it to just show the content you want (automatically) is more involved. An easy solution would be to load just the div you want in a separate page, use the jQuery `width()` and `height()` functions on the div, and then `window.resizeTo(width, height)`. Worth a try.

Comment: It does work in terms of resizing the window, but it includes the overhead/scrollbars. There'd be no way for me to account for this is there?

Comment: Hmm... You can remove tool bars with Javascript, but this won't help too much. I don't think there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: window.height is different from window.resize(h,w). Is it possible or wise to create some sort of loop that shrink the window till the inner window h/w is a specific number? For example, the resize script i have resizes the y to 644px, and i have a script that tells me the height of the window, which returns 520. So from that i would infer that the header is 124px tall, and that the use different sources for their values. I want 520, i determined 644 manually, with photoshop and a screenshot. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but it sounds like more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turns up this: http://members.iinet.net.au/~rkb/tips_HTML_window_size.htm

Just call `window.resizeTo(newWidth, newHeight)`.